# React and Serviceworker (Workbox)

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I`m trying to figure out how I can combine my react app with workbox as my serviceworker. No matter what I`m doing I always get the same error, while trying to register my serviceworker.

*Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').*

After I`ve done some research, most of the solutions turned out that it was caused by the dev environment. Is this true? And if so, how I can register a serviceworker, especially workbox, in a dev environment.

My Code Snippet inside my index.js

```
if( 'serviceWorker' in navigator ) {
   console.log("Supported!")
   navigator.serviceWorker
                   .register( 'sw.js' , { scope : ' ' } )
                   .then( function( ) {
                       console.log('Congratulations!!Service Worker Registered');
                   })
                   .catch( function() {
                       console.log(`Aagh! Some kind of Error :- `);
                   });
} else {
console.log("Not supported")
}
```

There's nothing more to my sw.js than a simple console.log

Comment: i forgot to tell you that the app was created with create-react-app

Comment: I suggest you to read this Medium: [Using Workbox with Create React App (Without Ejecting)](https://medium.com/@kevinah95/using-workbox-with-create-react-app-without-ejecting-b02b804854b)

Comment: Watch this and you will understand why you cannot do what you are trying to do. It wont work. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ok2r1M1jM_M and maybe check out this question also... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56252946/please-ensure-that-your-service-worker-file-contains-the-following-const-preca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things to check, 
1) create-react-app created a PWA app out of the box now(with SW and manifest.json files). Make sure you are not conflicting with the files created by that. I would recommend using what comes out of the box, unless you have an explicit reason to use Workbox, which should work with any framework/no framework, try what comes natively.

2) Make sure you are running your app in a server which supports HTTPS (with a cert) and service worker.

Comment: Your first point is absolutely correct. I finally managed it to register my Serviceworker with the following Package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewire-workbox